# Adding button opening e-mail client to MS CRM 2011 ribbon

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to add button sending e-mail with default client on MS CRM 2011 ribbon.

I've added following section to `customizations.xml`.

```
<CustomActions>
  <CustomAction Id="Company.{!EntityLogicalName}.MainTab.ContactSupport.CustomAction"
                Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.{!EntityLogicalName}.MainTab.ExportData.Controls._children"
                Sequence="72">
    <CommandUIDefinition>
      <Button Id="Company.{!EntityLogicalName}.MainTab.ContactSupport.Button"
              Command="Company.all.MainTab.HelpGroup.ContactSupport.Command"
              LabelText="Contact Support"
              ToolTipTitle="Contact project support via e-mail"
              ToolTipDescription="Contact project support via e-mail"
              TemplateAlias="o3"
              Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/senddirectmail_16.png"
              Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/senddirectmail_32.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CustomAction>
</CustomActions>
...
...
...
<CommandDefinitions>
  <CommandDefinition Id="Company.all.MainTab.HelpGroup.ContactSupport.Command">
    <EnableRules />
    <DisplayRules />
    <Actions>
      <Url Address="mailto:Support@support.com" />
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
</CommandDefinitions>
```

And it works. However on button click it opens new window. Which stays empty, since it's nothing to display — just call e-mail client.

Is there any workaround? How to start e-mail client without opening new window?

Comment: is an Internet Explorer issue, not so related to CRM

Comment: @Guido I'm using Firefox mostly. And behavior is the same in both browsers.

Comment: ok, where is located exactly this button? inside the homepage bside the exporting tool only for a selected entity?

Comment: It's on main application ribbon, on every entity, nearby "Advanced Find" button. Rightmost location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

Change your action to a JavaScript one, like:

```xml
<Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="contactsupport"  Library="$webresource:new_contactsupport.js" />
</Actions>
```

and the `contactsupport` function will be:

```js
function contactsupport() {
   location.href = 'mailto:Support@support.com';
}
```

looks like that setting `location.href` inside CRM doesn't change the url, but works to launch the application associated to `mailto`

tested with IE 9, Chrome 27, Firefox 21